# Linux access point as tunnel splitter

Tags: networking, vpn, bridge, access-point, split-tunnel

Since at my workplace they use Cisco VPNs (AnyConnect protocol) to reach production and test servers, i need to be always connected to work on those servers.

The problem is that the VPN doesn't implement split-tunneling, so i'm left with either connect to the internet or dev servers (dev servers are on the lan segment) or connect to the production or test servers.

I came up with the idea of using a Raspberry Pi 3 to split the vpn with the use of this awesome tool, called vpn-slice (https://github.com/dlenski/vpn-slice)

Indeed it works, and from the raspberry i can reach internet, vpn servers and lan segment.

**The problems are now these:**

- The pc connected to hostapd can navigate to internet, but no lan access (lan is on 192.168.32.1/22 and internal wifi access point is  192.100.100.1/24) i think i may need a bridge, but never really configured one (i'm not that of a network guy)
- I cannot access the vpn, since in on another dev (tun0)

so, this is the output of my ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.33.112  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.35.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe8b:bc4a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:8b:bc:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 335923  bytes 94865354 (90.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38890  bytes 12941447 (12.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 176  bytes 13688 (13.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 176  bytes 13688 (13.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1239
        inet 192.168.249.52  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.249.52
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 2  bytes 198 (198.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 166 (166.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.100.100.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.100.100.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fede:e91f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:de:e9:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 39416  bytes 12108156 (11.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 56938  bytes 61317586 (58.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And this is my route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.32.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.128.231.134  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.129.127.46   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.129.127.48   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
x.224.64.x      192.168.32.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.100.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.32.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and this is what i use to masquerade the wireless access point (wlan0) to the internet:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have no idea how to route wlan0 to eth0 family (lan) and to tun0 (vpn) servers (note that i need only the specific server contained into the route command)

Thanks to anyone that will help!

Comment: Ok, so apparently i can reach lan segment, so all it takes is to redirect certain tunnel traffic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i figured out what was the problem.

Since my default policy is to accept forward traffic, no point in having the forward rules (otherwise i would have needed even wlan0 <--> tun0 forward rules)

All i need to do was to masquerading even tun0, so the address can get rewritten.

I used:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now i can access internet, lan and vpn

Hope this helps someone!